# nodejs installation on openshift - how to add --harmony flag to startup

Tags: node.js, openshift

I'm trying to deploy an app of mine using openshift PaaS. Everything working fine so far, the only thing I couldn't accomplish was to set the `--harmony` flag when node starts up.

They're using `node-supervisor` to startup the process but won't add the options I added to the `node.env` file :(

anyone ever ran into the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use a DIY gear and have the action hook call the custom command to launch it.  Right now there is no way to modify the supervisor script to add additional flags.

Comment: Can you provide a simple example of such script?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me if I add the harmony flag to `main` property in my `package.json`.
i.e.

```
    "main": "--harmony server.js"
```

instead of

```
    "main": "server.js"
```

I'm also using https://github.com/ramr/nodejs-custom-version-openshift, so not sure if this works without that.